# empirical standard deviation and model standard errors in simulation studies

Tags: r, simulation

I'm running a simulation in meta-analysis to compare two methods that estimate the same problem parameters. One of them is a likelihood-based approach. In this kind of problems, one has to fix in advance a number of parameters, such as nn number of data sets we need to apply the method on, the true value of the parameters, etc. In the end, I stored a matrix with the estimates of parameters in my case 5 (the matrix is called estimas, dimension nn*5) and matrix of standard errors (the matrix is called st_err). Then I eventually compute for each estimate the mean of model based s.e. and the empirical standard deviation.

```
  st_error<-apply(st_err,2,mean)    #model based s.e.
  st_dev<-apply(estimas,2,function(x)sqrt(var(x)))   #empirical based
```

In practice these two should be very close, being this a signal that the simulation exercise is correct. My results are not that encouraging. For instance for one of the parameters I get,

```
Empirical standard error Model-based standard error:
1.3660                         4.7237
0.9370                         1.1601
0.6553                         0.5365
```

In one case they are way too different. Can anyone provide insight into why this is happening?

Sorry for the long message.
This is the code for the likelihood function:

```
lik.to.optim <- function(theta, data){

    mu.alpha <- theta[1]
    beta <- theta[2]
    mu.xi <- theta[3]
    sigma2.xi <- theta[4]
    sigma2.alpha<- theta[5]

    if(sigma2.xi <= 0 | sigma2.alpha <=0)
      return(NA)
    else{
      Sigma<-matrix(c(sigma2.alpha + beta^2*sigma2.xi, beta*sigma2.xi, beta*sigma2.xi, sigma2.xi), 2,2)

      ris<-sum(sapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) dmvnorm(as.vector(data[i,1:2]),c(mu.alpha+beta*mu.xi, mu.xi),
                                                        Sigma+diag(as.vector(data[i,3:4])), log=T))) 

    }
    return(ris)
  }

#----------------- Compute quantities-------------------#

p<-5 #number of param.

  estimas<-matrix(NA,n.sim,p)
  st_err<-matrix(NA,n.sim,p)

  truevalues<- c(mu.alpha, beta, mu.xi, sigma2.xi, sigma2.alpha)
  mat_truevalues<-matrix(rep(truevalues),n.sim,p,byrow=T) #matrix with true parameters
  zq<-matrix(rep(qnorm(0.95)),n.sim,p,byrow = T)#matrix with zquantile

  #Obtain mle stimates
  for(i in 1:n.sim){

    data<-lista[[i]]
    mle<-optim(c(0,1,-1,2,1), lik.to.optim, data=data, control=list(fnscale=-1)) 
    hessiano0 <- hessian(lik.to.optim, x=mle$par, data=data)

    estimas[i,]<-mle$par
    result = tryCatch({
      st_err[i,]<-sqrt(diag(solve(-hessiano0)))
    }, warning=function(w){
      #kkkkk
    }, error=function(e) {
      #kkkkk
    }, finally={

    })
    print(i)
  }

  #Need an index to take out simulation where NA are present
  index<- which(!is.na(apply(estimas+st_err,1,sum)))

  err_rate<-(n.sim - length(index))/n.sim #error rate of the simulation

  #Compute all quantities
  mean<-apply(estimas[index,],2,mean) 
  st_error<-apply(st_err[index,],2,mean) 
  st_dev<-apply(estimas[index,],2,function(x)sqrt(var(x)))


Besides to see the asymptotic behaviour I increased the number of the sample size,
and see what happens with s.e. and st. dev. these are some results for just one parameter:[enter image description here][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

[image: ![sample size vs standard erros and standard dev]

As you can see se and st. dev get further as I increase the sample size. I don't get why.

Comment: We would need to see some code how you obtained st_err and estimas.